# How to drop observations with inter-row difference being less than a specific value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that consists of several groups (hierarchical panel/longitude dataset to be more specific), and one cell within a group looks like this

```
z <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), 
            t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) 
# that is:
#        x          t
#  1: 10.0 1970-01-28
#  2: 10.5 1970-02-02
#  3: 11.1 1970-02-03
#  4: 14.0 1970-02-04
#  5: 14.2 1970-02-06 # to be removed since 14.2-14.0 = 0.2 <0.5
#  6: 14.4 1970-02-07 # to be removed since 14.4-14.2 = 0.2 <0.5 and 14.4-14.0 = 0.4 <0.5
#  7: 14.6 1970-02-08 # shall NOT be removed because 14.6-14.0 = 0.6 > 0.5
#  8: 17.0 1970-02-09
#  9: 17.4 1970-02-10 # to be removed
# 10: 30.0 1970-02-11
```

For simplicity, the groups are excluded, so just assume there is only two variables (columns) from the data:

I need to drop the observations with inter-row differences that are less than 0.5 between any two rows nearby, so what I need would like this

```
#        x          t
#  1: 10.0 1970-01-31
#  2: 10.5 1970-02-02
#  3: 11.1 1970-02-03
#  4: 14.0 1970-02-04
#  7: 14.6 1970-02-08
#  8: 17.0 1970-02-09
# 10: 30.0 1970-02-11
```

Finally it satisfies that any two values in neighbor has no less than 0.5 difference in the order of the variable t.

Is it possible for a data.table like this, but much larger, with several groups and nearly 100 million observations.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `Error in as.Date.numeric(c(27, 32:34, 36:41)) : 'origin' must be supplied`

Comment: @NelsonGon try : as.Date.numeric(c(27, 32:34, 36:41),origin="1970-01-01")

Comment: Thanks @Soren for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do:

```
library(data.table)

z <- z[, filt := min(x), by = cumsum(c(1, +(x >= shift(x) + 0.5)[-1]))][
  , filt := ifelse(x == filt, 
                   shift(x, fill = x[1]), 
                   filt)][
                     x - filt >= 0.5 | x == filt, ][, filt := NULL]
```

Explanation:

- First we calculate the minimum of `x` by each group;
- Group is created by `cumsum(c(1, +(x >= shift(x) + 0.5)[-1]))`. Therein, we check for each row whether `x >= shift(x) + 0.5` (difference between `x` and previous row is larger or equal to 0.5). This evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` which we turn to 1 and 0 with the `+` sign; as the first row will always be `NA` (as there is no previous one), we remove it with `[-1]` after the expression. As this means the first value will be missing from the vector, we construct another one which begins with 1 and is followed by what we have computed before. Afterwards we apply the `cumsum` - the latter assigns a value each time when there is a new row larger or equal than previous one + 0.5; if there is no such row in-between, it continues assigning the last number (as we have inserted 1 as the beginning of vector, it will start at 1 and increase by +1 every time it'll encounter the row which satisfied the condition for non-exclusion);
- There will be rows with only 1 row per previously created groups; in this case, we need to cross-check for difference with the exact previous row. In all other cases we cross-check for difference with the first row of the group (i.e. last row which should not be deleted according to criteria as it was larger than previous one + 0.5);
- After that we just remove those rows which don't satisfy the condition plus we keep the row which is equal to itself (will always be the first one); we remove the filtering variable at the end.

Output:

```
      x          t
1: 10.0 1970-01-28
2: 10.5 1970-02-02
3: 11.1 1970-02-03
4: 14.0 1970-02-04
5: 14.6 1970-02-08
6: 17.0 1970-02-09
7: 30.0 1970-02-11
```

Comment: Thank you! That's genius and also hard to digest. Could you please tell me how to interpret <code>+(x > shift(x) + 0.5)[-1]</code>? I dont understand the uses of <code>+( ...)</code> and  <code>[-1]</code>.

Comment: You're welcome! Of course, will add a short description.

Comment: I really appreciate that.  I thought <code>by </code> can be only used to control on specific group variables, but did not know it is so flexible for using in nested conditions. 

Comment: Indeed - it's very flexible & invisible at the same time - you don't need to remove it later on, can smoothly continue with the rest.

Comment: I see it when using paste( ) with collapse. Thx, bro!

Answer (score 1):

As the gap is dependent on the sequential removal of the rows, the solution below uses an interative approach to identify and re-calculate the subsequent gap after a row is removed.

```
z <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), 
                t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) 
setkeyv(z,"t")

find_gaps <- function(dt) {
  dt[, last_x := shift(.SD, n=1, fill=NA, type="lag"), .SDcols="x"]
  gaps <- dt[,abs(x-last_x) < 0.5,]
  gap <- which(gaps==TRUE)[1]
  #print(paste0("Removing row: ",gap))
  return (gap)
}

while(!is.na(gap<-find_gaps(z))) { z <- z[-gap] }

z
```

Results:

```
[1] "removing row: 5"
[1] "removing row: 5"
[1] "removing row: 7"
> z
      x          t last_x   gap
1: 10.0 1970-01-28     NA FALSE
2: 10.5 1970-02-02   10.0 FALSE
3: 11.1 1970-02-03   10.5 FALSE
4: 14.0 1970-02-04   11.1 FALSE
5: 14.6 1970-02-08   14.0 FALSE
6: 17.0 1970-02-09   14.6 FALSE
7: 30.0 1970-02-11   17.0 FALSE
```

#### Alternate

Noting the 8gb file and an eye for efficiency: proposing a good old for loop() as the most efficient

```
z1 <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) ; setkeyv(z1,"t")
x <- z1$x
last_x <- x[1]
gaps <- c()

for (i in 2:length(x))
{
  if (abs(x[i]-last_x) < 0.5) gaps <- c(gaps,i)
  else last_x <- x[i]
}
z1 <- z1[-(gaps)]
```

#### Benchmarking

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=100,
  forway={
    z1 <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) ; setkeyv(z1,"t")
    x <- z1$x; last_x <- x[1];  gaps <- c()

    for (i in 2:length(x)) { if (abs(x[i]-last_x) < 0.5) { gaps <- c(gaps,i); } else { last_x <- x[i]; } }
    z1 <- z1[-(gaps)]
  },
  datatableway={
    z2 <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) ; setkeyv(z2,"t")

    z2 <- z2[, filt := min(x), by = cumsum(c(1, +(x >= shift(x) + 0.5)[-1]))][, filt := ifelse(x == filt, shift(x, fill = x[1]), filt)][x - filt >= 0.5 | x == filt, ][, filt := NULL]
  },
  whileway={
    z3 <- data.table(x = c(10, 10.5, 11.1, 14, 14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 17, 17.4, 30), t = as.Date(c(27, 32:34, 36:41))) ; setkeyv(z3,"t")

    find_gaps <- function(dt) {
      dt[, last_x := shift(.SD, n=1, fill=NA, type="lag"), .SDcols="x"]
      gaps <- dt[,abs(x-last_x) < 0.5,]
      which(gaps==TRUE)[1]
    }
    while(!is.na(gap<-find_gaps(z3))) { z3 <- z3[-gap] }
  }
)

(z1==z2) & (z2==z3[,.(x,t)])
```

#### Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
       forway  2.741609  3.607341  4.067566  4.069382  4.556219  5.61997   100
 datatableway  7.552005  8.915333  9.839475  9.606205 10.762764 15.46430   100
     whileway 13.903507 19.059612 20.692397 20.577014 22.243933 27.44271   100
> 
> (z1==z2) & (z2==z3[,.(x,t)])
        x    t
[1,] TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE
[6,] TRUE TRUE
[7,] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very intuitive.

Comment: Made an update for fastest approach -- a simply for() loop it seems!

Comment: Thx! It's indeed fast, just not that convenient to use for/while loop inside a data.table, especially with groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::mutate` and `filter`:

```
z %>%
  mutate(diff = lead(x, 1) - x) %>%
  filter(diff >= 0.5 | is.na(diff)) %>%
  select(-diff)
```

I kept `diff` field for easy understanding purpose. You can do this in single filter statement also

Comment: It's not given the desired results.

Comment: Why row 7 should not be removed?

Comment: I think the OP is thinking about a solution that removes a row and then compares the next subsequent row with the last non-removed row.

Comment: This does not work because the row#7 would be removed, but I need to keep it. I've tried to calculate from the 1-st to N-th difference and generate tag to label them if it is qualified to removed, but very tedious and inefficient for a huge dataset (about 8GB size).

Comment: You said `between any two rows nearby` , so should it only only for +/- 2 rows ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up precise words. It's not just +/- 2, it can be more than 2 but less than the length of the variable t.